# Is it "disappearing" or "disappearance" in this case?

Tags: word-usage

Is it "disappearing" or "disappearance" in this case?

> Moreover, they are causing the **disappearing** of several lakes, which are endemic wetlands of my region vital to the wildlife.

Comment: It is disappear**a**nce (spelling)

Comment: And I am very dubious about the usage of “endemic.”

Comment: @JeffMorrow why is that?

Comment: Because “endemic” is usually used in reference to fauna, flora, and disease, not topography. Moreover, it means to “be present” and you are discussing not being present.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Lakes are ecosystems not just topography. They contain fauna, flora and topography. The ecosystems as a whole can be endemic of specific regions because, as in this case, they just appear in specific regions like this one. I didn't understand your reference to *be present*. Although these lakes are disappearing, there are still some of them, if that what you were referring to.

Comment: I just fine "endemic" really strange. I'd probably stop reading at that point. "Lakes" are fairly large bodies of water, not "wetlands," which are bogs, marshes, etc. Things that are disappearing are not endemic, and the word "endemic" is not usually applied in common speech to large-scale features of the earth. No one says "Oceans are endemic."

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use the word disappearance. If you want to use disappearing your sentence could look like this:

> Moreover, they are the cause of several lakes disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

> Moreover, they are causing the **disappearing** of several lakes, which are endemic wetlands of my region vital to the wildlife.

**disappearing** is incorrect here, because it is a verb, and you want to describe the result, which would take a noun form of the word. Hence **disappearance** would be the correct choice. Similarly, the following sentence would go:

> Moreover, they are **the** cause **of the disappearance** of several lakes, which are endemic wetlands of my region vital to the wildlife.

> Moreover, they are causing several lakes **to disappear**, which are endemic wetlands of my region vital to the wildlife.